# Calculating the angular direction from velocity

Tags: 2d, physics, javascript, html-canvas

I'm trying to calculate the angular direction of a projectile, knowing it's X and Y velocity I can find the magnitude of its movement, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around getting the angular direction (in radians) that it is moving...

I assume there is a `tan` or a `sin` involved, but I'm a bit clueless otherwise...

Comment: As a side note ... *why*? Most calculations for a game, including rotations by the same angle, you can do without touching trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

read the following page you have to use atan2 : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan.asp

so `angle = atan2 (vy,vx);` and `speed = sqrt(vy*vy + vx * vx)`

Comment: Nothing wrong with the W3Schools page, but just to let you know: http://W3Fools.com

Answer (score 0):

angle = tan_inverse(VelocityY/VelocityX)